# What is the electric field between two plates with a hole each (the holes also parallel)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, acceleration, capacitance

Suppose you have two charged parallel plates, and an electron on the negative plate. It would move in the electric field to the positive plate. If, however, there was a hole on each of the plates, positioned so that an electron could move through the holes, would there still be an electric field in that section, allowing the electron to be accelerated through the holes? Sorry if i didn't explain my question very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upto what I can understand from your question, i think that the field will be halved in the vicinity of the hole, an effect generally seen in conductors. Here is an illustration for your hint-[image]

**Ref**: NCERT Physics class 12 chapter 1

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.

Comment: Answers that rely heavily on images (like this one) are frowned upon here.  Better to actually write out the information in text so that it can be indexed properly and so that those using screen-readers can actually use this answer.